# Hide Mobile Number from Indexing in google

Tags: javascript, html, web, indexing, search-engine

i have a website , which uses simple HTML...

I have used < table > tag of HTML for creating a table in the html web page..

In that table one column is for mobile number, so i have listed all mobile numbers in that table column.

My problem is once the website go live.. the entire mobile numbers will become public in internet.

I want to stop these mobile numbers to go public..how to stop index only these mobile numbers by search engines ..or anyway to hide the mobile number ..like expand and collapse..or a JavaScript popup which shows the mobile number rather than from the html page..

Your thoughts are invited..

Comment: Simply never ever populate personal information on your public website. Even on intranet sites this is not always a good idea.
Email addresses and phone numbers should always be hidden.
This is just basic security, not only google will find those information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hide the table with JavaScript it only makes it invisible for humans, the code and numbers are still visible for search engine bots to see.

Why do you need to publish the numbers to the internet if you don't want them to be visible? And where are those numbers? Inside a log-in only area? I need some more information to help you.

If they're on a public page (for example yoursite.com/contact.html) but should not be crawled by bots you can create a robots.txt file and put it in your root with he following written inside:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /contact.html
```

Anyway this is **not** save at all, bots could still crawl the page without publishing the data they collected.

As I said I need more information about your page to help you.